# App crashes when push to new route with error: Response<dynamic>>(dirty, state

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make it that the user must be logged in when veiwing specific pages. If not it redirects them to the login page.
I have the following code, but when I add Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login'); I get an error:

> The following assertion was thrown building
> FutureBuilder<Response>(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState<Response>#458f7):

```
return FutureBuilder<Response>(
  future: Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context).fetchAllLocations(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
        return Text('Fetch Items');
        break;
      case ConnectionState.active:
        return Text('is active');
        break;
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return Text('Is Fetching');
        break;
      case ConnectionState.done:
        if (snapshot.data.status == Status.ERROR)
          return Text('errrrrrroooorr');
        else if (snapshot.data.status == Status.UNAUTHENTICATED) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
          return Container();
        }

        return MyWidget();
        break;
      default:
        return Text('hy');
    }
  },
);
```

Also, how can I make this code reusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addPostFrameCallback` 
code snippet

```
 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
                });
```

working demo

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
              title: "demo",
            ),
        '/login': (context) => Login(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<String> _future;

  Future<String> fetchAllLocations() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    Future.value("test");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = fetchAllLocations();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                  return Text('none');
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                case ConnectionState.active:
                  return Text('');
                case ConnectionState.done:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text(
                      '${snapshot.error}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                    );
                  } else {
                    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/login');
                    });
                    return Container();
                  }
              }
            }));
  }
}

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to first screen when tapped.
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```